# Is it safe to store jwt access token in httpOnly cookie?

Tags: authentication, security, jwt, authorization

I watched a guide where an author stored access token in localStorage and then he put the access token as Authorization header with value "Bearer accessToken" in every request through axios interceptor. But I am wondering why not to store access token in httpOnly cookie as we do it with refresh token. What would be the problem if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's safer to store access tokens in HTTP-only, secure, same-site cookies (it doesn't matter if it's a JWT access token). It's safer because the value of the access token can't be stolen through a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. However, when you keep the access token in a cookie, you won't be able to send it to an API in an `Authorization` header. The browser doesn't have a way of setting the authorization header, it only attaches the cookies. That means that you might need a piece of software that will sit between your front end and API, and extract the access token from the cookie (this can be done e.g., by an API gateway).

Remember also that storing access tokens in cookies leaves you open to cross-site request forgery attacks (CSRF), but there are [well-established techniques](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) to protect yourself from CSRF. It is also simpler to protect against CSRF than against XSS.

Comment: Doesn't samesite=strict attribute actually protect our cookie from CSRF?

Comment: It does help mitigate these attacks, but there are scenarios where you don't want the cookie to have the `strict` value, as it can hinder functionality. Also, no security solution is 100% bullet-proof so you need to make sure to follow all the recommendations.

Comment: `However, when you keep the access token in a cookie, you won't be able to send it to an API in an Authorization header` > 

My question is why would you want the user to send retrieve the token and send it back in the header, when it can just send a normal request while the browser attaches the corresponding "HttpOnly" cookie with it.

Comment: Many APIs require sending tokens in the Authorization header and don't accept cookies.